# Android OutOfMemory error & LruCache

Tags: android, out-of-memory

First things first, I know there's plenty of related posts, I've read lots of them, none of them helped and I'm out of ideas :)

So i'm developing an android app (sdk version 14+) which uses lots of images (for buttons, logos, displaying lot's of images and so on). Average image size is 120kb +- 100kb

As title says I'm gettin OutOfMemory error. At first i added image source to ImageViews in xml or programmatically using setImageResource. Soon app started to crash due to OutOfMemory error. So I've read this ( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html ) tutorial and implemented LruCache as it says. I added bitmaps to lrucache and then used the get method to set bitmap to imageview.

In activity's onDestroy method I call evictAll method on lrucache and I set lrucache to null. So I presume, the memory is freed then.

However problem still persists, when I go through couple of activities, the app crashes.

Help much appreciated :)

Comment: Have you tried using disk cache? http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html

Comment: Are you putting all ur images in drawable folder? If u r then try putting them in different drawable-?dpi folders according to ur device's density...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation exceeding max available VM memory will throw an OutOfMemory exception. Seems like  caching bitmaps exceeds the virtual memory available.

Recycle bitmaps when not in use.

```
 bitmap.recycle();
```

[When should I recycle a bitmap using LRUCache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10743381/when-should-i-recycle-a-bitmap-using-lrucache). Have a look at the accepted answer by commonsware.

I believe that when the LRUCache evicts an image to make room for another one, the memory is not being freed.(Asked by user in the above link)

It won't be, until the Bitmap is recycled or garbage-collected.(answer by commomsware).

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk. Talks about memory management, memory leaks and using MAT Analyzer.

Comment: I'm still trying to fix the problem. I'm calling recycle method on bitmap in entryRemoved method of lrucache class but it does not solve the problem. I thought it would work, because I add all necessary images to cache in activity's onCreate method. The images are then used through activity lifetime.

Comment: use mat analyzer to find and fix problem

Comment: my app is using more memory and heap goes on increasing..and giving OOM.?solution

Comment: @GvSharma without much information no one can suggest anything. If its because of image downscale it. Check out Android Performance Patterns on Google Plus Community

Answer (score 4):

Thanks guys you helped me a lot!

So if anyone surfs to this question with same problem, here are some guidelines:

- call .recycle() on bitmaps when you don't need them anymore.
- use Eclipse Memory Analyzer to find your problems
- (must) see [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk) video
- [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709603/mat-eclipse-memory-analyzer-how-to-view-bitmaps-from-memory-dump/12709604#12709604) how to view bitmaps from your .hprof file

Answer (score 1):

Are you storing all your images in the heap? If so, you should cache them in the sd card or the internal storage, and keep just a bunch of them in the heap (a nice approach is to use a LRU cache).

If you're already doing this... you can download the memory analyzer tool and debug your app's memory usage.

http://www.eclipse.org/mat/

Dealing with OutOfMemoryError can be really painful.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks for reply, but the thing is that i need all images throughout activity's lifetime. I believe that some images persist in memory even when activity is destroyed, because the error occurs only when i'm "cycling" through couple of activites (sometimes error occurs relatively early, sometimes not).