# Bitmap Out Of Memory on a Photo taken

Tags: java, android, camera, android-camera

I have a camera that I use to take pictures and my problem is on the onPictureTaken function:

```
public Camera.PictureCallback jpeghandler = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inScaled = false;
        options.inDither = false;
        options.inSampleSize = 2;
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        photo = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, options);

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(90);
        Bitmap rotate_bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(photo , 0, 0, photo.getWidth(), photo.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        photo.recycle();
        photo = Bitmap.createBitmap(rotate_bitmap, 0, rotate_bitmap.getHeight()/2 - rotate_bitmap.getWidth()/2, rotate_bitmap.getWidth(), rotate_bitmap.getWidth());

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
        String image_url = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), photo, "photo" , null);
        resultIntent.putExtra("Photo_Taken", image_url);
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);

        photo.recycle();
        rotate_bitmap.recycle();
        finish();

    }

};
```

I have another activity that opens this one and then I take a picture, closing this one and passing the location of the image back to the first activity. The problem is that when I reopen this activity to take another picture it gives me an Out Of Memory error on this line:

```
Bitmap rotate_bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(photo , 0, 0, photo.getWidth(), photo.getHeight(), matrix, true);
```

What is wrong and what is happening? Cause the photo size is always under 25Mb and then in the second photo it appears this: Out of memory on a 13128976-byte allocation.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your heap gets full [ (image data) + (other data) > (heap size) ]. I believe you have two instances of your photo stored on heap (when second activity is launched, data (including photo) from first activity is not yet cleared from memory).

If you're using Eclipse I strongly recommend installing [Memory Analyzer (MAT)](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/)

Check [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15496394/android-outofmemory-error-lrucache) for more info.