# Using LruCache and avoid OutOfMemoryException

Tags: android, out-of-memory, soft-references, android-lru-cache

There's an activity in my app whose showing around `1000` very small sized bitmaps (Around `20kb` each bitmap). After it loads some of the bitmaps, there's an `OutOfMemoryException`.

I was first reading about `SoftReference` and it looked like it will solve my problem about the `OOM exceptions`. But then, I read that it won't cache my bitmaps and will free them "too soon", so it will have to decode the bitmap again and "waste" time.So, I implemented the `LruCache`.

How can I make sure that I will not get `OOM exception` when implementing my `LruCache`?

Maybe I should just use the SoftReference, because my main target is to avoid `OOM`

Or, this might be my solution? [LruSoftCache](http://blog.wu-man.com/2012/01/lrucache-with-softreference-on-android.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When implementing `LruCache`, you should specify the cache size, and tell it how to calculate the size for each object (in this case, the object is bitmap).

You can use the following sample:

```
// uses 1/8th of the memory for the cache
final int cacheSize = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 8L);
LruCache bitmapCache = new LruCache(cacheSize) {
   protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap value) {
       return value.getByteCount();
}}
```

Comment: What happens if it exceeds the specified memory? does it free the other allocated bitmaps to avoid the memory exception?

Comment: Yes, the least recent used bitmap will be removed from the cache, and will be garbage collected if it's not referenced by other objects.

Comment: "will be garbage collected" means that it will be recycled? bitmap.recycle()

Comment: As you can see here, there's a chance for an outofmemory exception, when using LruCache, it garbage collects the bitmap but doesn't recycle it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10743381/when-should-i-recycle-a-bitmap-using-lrucache

Comment: As far as I know, `bitmap.recycle()` is only needed for pre-honeycomb devices, where the bitmap is not stored in JVM, so there's a chance that you'll get OOM even if no object is referencing the bitmap, but the heap is not freed yet. Then if you're targeting those devices, you need to have some reference counter for the bitmap yourself.

Comment: Actually, I am targeting also pre-honeycomb devices (min api level is 9), do I have to use the following LruCache for pre-honeycomb:http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/util/LruCache.html  and use the following LruCache for honeycomb and on? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html  or..?

Comment: well, if your min api level is 9, you have to use the support package.

Comment: I don't quite understand why there's also a package for honeycomb devices. Why there are 2 of those LruCache?

Comment: Sorry for digging too much about this, but it is a very important part of my app, to prevent those OOM. I wouldn't care if only pre-honeycomb devices might get OOM, but I want to assure that it won't happen on honeycomb devices and on. If I still use the support package and not the other one (the util), will it be OK?

Comment: The `LruCache` class was introduced in API level 12, so you can't use it in older devices. That's why Android devs backported it to the support package so that you can use it for API level 4 and above (including API level 12 and above). For the OOM issue, if you use `LruCache` for honeycomb and above, you don't need to call `recycle()` at all; but for pre-honeycomb devices, you need to call if no one is referencing the bitmap to make sure it's immediately released.