# How to solve java.lang.OutOfMemoryError trouble in Android

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory, bitmapfactory, setbackground

Altough I have very small size image in drawable folder, I am getting this error from users. And I am not using any bitmap function in code. At least intentionally :)

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:683)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:513)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:889)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3436)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1909)
    at android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(View.java:16251)
    at com.autkusoytas.bilbakalim.SoruEkrani.cevapSecimi(SoruEkrani.java:666)
    at com.autkusoytas.bilbakalim.SoruEkrani$9$1.run(SoruEkrani.java:862)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

According to this stackTrace I'm gettin this error at this line ('tv' is a textView):

```
tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yanlis);
```

What is the problem? If you need some other information about code, I can add it.
Thanks!

Comment: Have you read this ? http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: Try this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19558713/android-java-lang-outofmemoryerror

Comment: No, but as I said I have very small size image (max 600kb). I guess this is for larger image. @2Dee

Comment: hello @Utku, can you explain if you solved the problem?

Answer (score 6):

I see only two options:

1. You have memory leaks in your application.
2. Devices do not have enough memory when running your application.

Comment: So how can I fix memory leaks in my app?

Comment: By detecting the places which generate & store a lot of data (usually it's due to the problem with not releasing the images). You might find this helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298208/how-to-discover-memory-usage-of-my-application-in-android

Answer (score 5):

Few hints to handle such error/exception for Android Apps:

1. Activities & Application have methods like:

   - onLowMemory
   - onTrimMemory
     Handle these methods to watch on memory usage.
2. tag in Manifest can have attribute 'largeHeap' set to TRUE, which requests more heap for App sandbox.
3. Managing in-memory caching & disk caching:

   - Images and other data could have been cached in-memory while app running, (locally in activities/fragment and globally); should be managed or removed.
4. Use of WeakReference, SoftReference of Java instance creation , specifically to files.
5. If so many images, use proper library/data structure which can manage memory, use samling of images loaded, handle disk-caching.
6. Handle OutOfMemory exception
7. Follow best practices for coding

   - Leaking of memory (Don't hold everything with strong reference)
8. Minimize activity stack e.g. number of activities in stack (Don't hold everything on context/activty)

   - Context makes sense, those data/instances not required out of scope (activity and fragments), hold them into appropriate context instead global reference-holding.
9. Minimize the use of statics, many more singletons.
10. Take care of OS basic memory fundametals

    - Memory fragmentation issues
11. Involk GC.Collect() manually sometimes when you are sure that in-memory caching no more needed.

Comment: Can you please share code how to handle OutOfMemory exception

Answer (score 5):

If you are getting this Error java.lang.OutOfMemoryError this is the most common problem occurs in Android. This error is thrown by the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) when an object cannot be allocated due to lack of memory space.

Try this `android:hardwareAccelerated="false" , android:largeHeap="true"`in your 
 manifest.xml file under application like this:

```
<application
  android:name=".MyApplication"
  android:allowBackup="true"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
  android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
  android:largeHeap="true" />
```

Comment: Why I should make `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"`? if I make it true then what happens?

Comment: if you write hardwareAccelerated="false"   , then in your project you wont get elevation for Cardview , think about it?

Answer (score 4):

You should implement an LRU cache manager when dealing with bitmap

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html
[When should I recycle a bitmap using LRUCache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10743381/when-should-i-recycle-a-bitmap-using-lrucache)

OR

Use a tier library like Universal Image Loader :

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

EDIT :

Now when dealing with images and most of the time with bitmap I use Glide which let you configure a Glide Module and a LRUCache

https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Answer (score 0):

`android:largeHeap="true"` didn't fix the error

In my case, I got this error after I added an icon/image to Drawable folder by converting SVG to vector. Simply, go to the icon xml file and set small numbers for the width and height

```
android:width="24dp"
android:height="24dp"
android:viewportWidth="3033"
android:viewportHeight="3033"
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Check the image size

I was loading a ~350kB image in an imageview directly via XML (`app:srcCompat`) which was resulting in OOM error and the application crashed.

To solve it, I loaded the exact same image using Glide into the same imageview and it worked!

> #### Lesson: Reduce image size / defer loading of image