# How to resolve java.lang.OutOfMemoryError exception when converting image url to bitmap in android?

Tags: java, android, bitmap

This is the method i wrote to get image from url to bitmap, and i have made to run whenever i scroll down the main view using `Handler`

```
public void setimage(final ImageView imageview, final String urll,final int postion)
{

new Thread(new Runnable() 
 {

    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(urll);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            final Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

            handler.post(new Runnable() 
            {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    imageview.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myBitmap, 160, 140, true));
                }
            });

            web.get(postion).setImage(myBitmap);

        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

}).start();

}
```

This is the exception i am getting in Custom adapter whenever i scroll down to view more images in `logcat`

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
>   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)

Please let me know where i am doing wrong

Comment: Use lazy load, please refer to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/lazy-load-of-images-in-listview

Comment: i suggest you to use lib for load image rather than code yourself. Some lib are picasso , volley and universal loader

Comment: What about [inSampleSize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can request to use more by using

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

in the manifest.

Reference: [How to solve java.lang.OutOfMemoryError trouble in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25719620/how-to-solve-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-trouble-in-android/25719828#25719828)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the decodeStream's overload that accept, in the third parameter, a BitmapOptions to scale down size and image's quality.

Have a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeStream%28java.io.InputStream,%20android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options%29)

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Both answers are really not too good. Large heap can mean anything. On some devices it will be ok, on some it won't. Android does not provide any information about how big this heap will be. If your bitmap is really big, you should download it not to the ram memory, but to the flash (some file). And than immediately read it scaled down. In this method you also has a cache implementation for free :)

Please check this article http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Answer (score -1):

when you set bitmap before put this line

System.gc();

Comment: Java guarantees that GC will occur before this exception is thrown. The suggestion therefore accomplishes precisely nothing.