# Getting drawable identifier for name

Tags: android

Hi I cant find the solutiıon for my question. 
I take name of the images from db. And then I should give tat string to image.setImageResource. There are lots of answers which include `getResources().getIdentifier(`
But getResoruces() is not work. I get error like:
Error:(40, 21) error: cannot find symbol method getResources()
 How can I solve this problem thanks.

```
public class ReceivedItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ReceivedItem> {

    public ReceivedItemAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ReceivedItem> items){
        super(context,R.layout.row_item_received,items);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View customView = LayoutInflater.from(this.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.row_item_received, parent, false);

        ReceivedItem item = getItem(position);
        TextView textName = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
        TextView textCalorie = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.calorieTextView);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) customView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        textName.setText(item.getName());
        textCalorie.setText(item.getCalorie()+ " cal");
        String mDrawableName = item.getImageName();
        int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(mDrawableName , "drawable", getPackageName());
        imageView.setImageResource(resID);
        customView.setTag(item.getId());
        return customView;
    }
}
```

I use this code in a listview adapter class

Comment: please paste how and where are you calling getResources()

Comment: `getResources()` works. but you need a `context` to get access to this method

Comment: How can I add context ?

Comment: String mDrawableName = item.getImageName();
        int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(mDrawableName , "drawable", getPackageName());
        imageView.setImageResource(resID);

Comment: You don't add a context, you get it. I would recommend looking into the fundamentals of Android or things are only going to get more confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both answers are correct and work.

But it is easier to call

```
 int resID = customView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier(mDrawableName , "drawable", getPackageName());
```

You can do this, since every view has a reference to the context

> public final Context  getContext ()
>
> Returns the context the view is running in, through which it can
>   access the current theme, resources, etc.
>
> Returns Context The view's Context.

Comment: I get know ID: 7614
                                                                                       java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 17640012 byte allocation with 5184936 free bytes and 4MB until OOM
                                                                                           at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)

Comment: This is an other Problem, but probably your Images you try to load are to big

Comment: thank you I handle that problem by making them smaller. Is there any solution instead of making smaller?

Comment: there are several Solutions : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25719620/how-to-solve-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-trouble-in-android

Answer (score 1):

Please post some code, before we can help you.

If you want to access getResources outside and activity or similar, you need to get a reference to context and then call context.getResources.

Just call customView.getContext().getResources()

Comment: I edit my question. I want to acces it from listview adapter.

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep the context instance inside your adapter, and then call to context.getResources()

```
public class ReceivedItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ReceivedItem> {

private final Context context;

public ReceivedItemAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ReceivedItem> items){
    super(context,R.layout.row_item_received,items);
    this. context = context;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View customView = LayoutInflater.from(this.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.row_item_received, parent, false);

    ReceivedItem item = getItem(position);
    TextView textName = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
    TextView textCalorie = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.calorieTextView);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) customView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    textName.setText(item.getName());
    textCalorie.setText(item.getCalorie()+ " cal");
    String mDrawableName = item.getImageName();
    int resID = context.getResources().getIdentifier(mDrawableName , "drawable", getPackageName());
    imageView.setImageResource(resID);
    customView.setTag(item.getId());
    return customView;
}
```