# Android Studio - Failed to allocate a 39690012 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 13MB until OOM

Tags: android, out-of-memory

I am trying to load an activity with a lot of pictures that serve as logo and buttons.
Apparently it crashes because there is not enough memory to support them.

What is the best or most efficient way to do sucha  thing, as load the pictures I want without problems ?

Comment: Reduce the size of your images. Even better, try using **something else**. Try using drawables, 9 patches, SVGs, VectorDrawables, ... anything that can save you from using bitmaps (with the exception of 9 patches).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve java.lang.OutOfMemoryError trouble in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25719620/how-to-solve-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-trouble-in-android)

Comment: My pictures are in .png format, and they are about 28 KB. How smaller can they get ?

Comment: In memory, they become `x * y * 4 * dpi_scale_factor`

Answer (score 0):

I had look like this problem when use Genymotion emulator.so when i switch to default emulator of android studio this problem fixed although android studio emulator had less than memory than Genymotion emulator.
if your algorithms haven't problem but your application crashed you can use some technick
look like `cache`.
also if your image size is large you can reduce image size but you must have attention this work can reduce image resolution