# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Android

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-logcat

I am facing issue with load bitmap image in one of my activity with cropper library. I am getting outofmemory error if image size is more than 5 MB...I have tried

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

but it have not helped me for solve issue. My java code and logcat is like below

Logcat:

> 07-09 21:10:47.482: E/art(4870): Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to
>   allocate a 6391674 byte allocation with 6004224 free bytes and 5MB
>   until OOM"
>       07-09 21:10:47.482: D/AndroidRuntime(4870): Shutting down VM
>       07-09 21:10:47.522: E/AndroidRuntime(4870): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       07-09 21:10:47.522: E/AndroidRuntime(4870): Process: com.karopass.status2017, PID: 4870
>       07-09 21:10:47.522: E/AndroidRuntime(4870): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 6391674 byte
>   allocation with 6004224 free bytes and 5MB until OOM
>       07-09 21:10:47.522: E/AndroidRuntime(4870):   at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:122)
>       07-09 21:10:47.522: E/AndroidRuntime(4870):   at com.karopass.status2017.material.ImageLoader.addToDiskCache(ImageLoader.java:238)
>       07-09 21:10:47.522: E/AndroidRuntime(4870):   at com.karopass.status2017.material.ImageLoader.saveTempImage(ImageLoader.java:271)

as well my java code is like below

```
public File addToDiskCache(String imageName, Bitmap inImage) {

    Log.e("Add to Disk",imageName);

    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);

    if(!mCacheDir.exists()){
        mCacheDir.mkdirs();
    }

    File filePath=new File(mCacheDir.getPath()+File.separator+imageName);
    if(!filePath.exists()) {
        try {
            filePath.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    OutputStream os=null;
    try {
           os= new FileOutputStream(filePath.getPath());
            os.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            os.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Write err",filePath.toString());
        }finally {
        try {
            os.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    Log.e("storage path",filePath.toString());

    return filePath;
}
```

Please help me for solve issue.

Thanks

Comment: May be  a duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25719620/how-to-solve-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-trouble-in-android

Comment: maybe your bitmap is too large or maybe it is not caused by this method, check your other codes to see if you have forgot to recycle object, especially bitmap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

compress is ineffective

try this when you use bitmap from file

```
 private Bitmap sampleImage(Bitmap bitmap, int reqWidth, int reqHight) {


        //first decode
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile("FILE_PATH",options);
        //seconde deconde
        options.inSampleSize = caculateSampleSize(options,reqWidth,reqHight);
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;


        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("FILE_PATH",options);
         return bitmap;

    }

private int caculateSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHight) {
    int screenWidth;
    int screenHight;
    screenWidth = (reqWidth == 0 ? this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels : reqWidth);
    screenHight = (reqHight == 0 ? this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels : reqHight);
    int sampleWith = options.outWidth / screenWidth;
    int sampleHight = options.outHeight / screenHight;
    //use max
    return  sampleWith > sampleHight ? sampleWith : sampleHight;
}
```