# Memory issues on certain devices

Tags: java, android

I am having an interesting issue. I have two devices, a Verizon Ellipses 7 tablet (Piece of junk) and a Nexus 6 (Nice Device). I have a program that is VERY basic. When I run the app on the tablet it runs perfectly fine. When I try and run the app on the Nexus 6 it crashes with an Out of Memory error. What could be causing this? The Nexus 6 has more free memory than the tablet even has to begin with let alone free.

Comment: R u using any bitmap

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve java.lang.OutOfMemoryError trouble in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25719620/how-to-solve-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-trouble-in-android)

Comment: I'm using 10 PNG files that are each loaded into their own ImageView. Each PNG is roughly 375k.