# My App works fine on testing device but crashes when released on play store

Tags: java, android

I previously released an App on the play store with no problems, but i just released the update for that App and for some reason it opens but doesn't even load before saying "Unfortunately 'app name' keeps stopping". This App works perfectly when i test it on my device using a cable. Can you help me please.

I tried releasing the App by removing a resized bitmap image as i thought this might be the problem. But it was not. I tried multiple other tweaks to the code but to no avail. At this point in time i am clueless of what may be causing this issue as i tried everything i could think of.

Here is my gradle Code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com."
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 14
        versionName "1.4"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"



    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}


}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: add a stacktrace if you want help

Answer (score 1):

There was an error log on the play console. i looked at the error and realised i had a memory problem so i used this answer to solve it:

[How to solve java.lang.OutOfMemoryError trouble in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25719620/how-to-solve-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-trouble-in-android)